# cp-web "chaincode name may not be blank"

Tags: hyperledger

I've been getting this error upon deploying the cp-web hyperledger example code. As a note I haven't altered anything in the example code itself. It can register a user and I can log in, however when trying to view anything or creating a new commercial paper it doesn't seem to execute any of these commands. Any ideas on what could be wrong?

```
2016-05-09T13:14:21.661+1000[App/0]OUT error:
2016-05-09T13:14:21.661+1000[App/0]OUT data: 'Chaincode name may not be blank.' },
2016-05-09T13:14:21.661+1000[App/0]OUT { code: -32602,
2016-05-09T13:14:21.661+1000[App/0]OUT id: 1462763661637 }
2016-05-09T13:14:21.661+1000[App/0]OUTpapers undefined
2016-05-09T13:14:21.661+1000[App/0]OUT message: 'Invalid params',
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the path setup in your chaincode CLI or REST API call:

```
{                                                                                                                                                                                                               
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "method": "deploy",
  "params": {
    "type": 1,
    "chaincodeID":{
        "name": "cp-web",
        "path": "<path of the chaincode>"
    },   
    "ctorMsg": {
        "args":["what ever"]
    }    
  },   
  "id": 1
}
```